# Подскажите пожалуйста с bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, html5, bootstrap5

Решил использовать мега меню от бутстреп, то бишь Navbar. Использовал код от туда же, но появилась проблема, не могу найти параметр, отвечающий за открытие меню, при наведении. Я как-то совсем не могу понять, а где зарыта собака? Сидел читал описание, но ничего толкового не вычитал. Вопрос в том, как сделать так, чтобы список открывался не при нажатии мышки, а при наведении.

**Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Попытка сделать сайт</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    

    <div class="container">
        
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-9 offset-xl-3">
                <div class="menu header">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                              
                             <div class="menu collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                                  <ul class="knopki navbar-nav">
                                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                   <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="navigation" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Товары</a>
                                   <ul class="megamenu dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                     <li>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                                <img src="img/header-camera.jpg" alt="Idk">
                                                <p><a href="#"></a></p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                                <img src="img/header-camera.jpg" alt="">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                                <img src="img/header-camera.jpg" alt="Idk">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                                <img src="img/header-camera.jpg" alt="">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
                                        </div>
                                     </li>
                                   </ul>
                                   <li class="nav-item">
                                      <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Решения</a>
                                 </li>
                                 <li class="nav-item">
                                      <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Проектирование</a>
                                 </li>
                                 <li class="nav-item">
                                      <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Тех.поддержка</a>
                                 </li>
                                 <li class="nav-item">
                                      <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">О предприятии</a>
                                 </li>
                                 <li class="nav-item">
                                   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Наша История</a>
                                 </li>
                                
                                 </ul>
                                 
                             </div>
                             </div>
                        </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
          
        </div>
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu{
    float: right;
    transition: all 0.3s ease !important;
}

.nav-link {
    
    color: black !important;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    
    display: block;
    
}

.knopki a:hover{

    background: black !important;
    color: white !important;
    box-shadow: 1px 5px 10px -5px black !important;
    
    

}
 .megamenu{
    width: 800px;
    height: 330px;
    
 }
```

То что использовал с bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/